# Laravel - error outputting data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Error I get when I try to reach my site: example.dev in browser

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (SQL: select * from `products`)
```

I did migrate table before (I see newly added data @phpmyadmin), but when I try to output the data in my website, I get this error...

My configuration looks correct, but still:
.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=products
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=''
```

.database[php]

```
 'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'products'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
```

My approach of outputting data (maybe something went wrong here):

Make controller from bash console.
ProductController

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Requests;

    class ProductController extends Controller{
        public function getIndex(){
            $products = Product::all();
            return view('index.shop', ['products' => $products]);
        }
    }
```

Change routes file (web.php):

```
Route::get('/', [
'uses' => 'ProductController@getIndex',
'as' => 'product.index'
]);
```

HINT: When I tried to change controllers dir @ProductsController, I got other error: "Controller not found!". Maybe it's related!

Comment: Change `DB_PASSWORD=''` to `DB_PASSWORD=`

Comment: You are using an incorrect password. Is your root user without password? If yes, then try @DaanMeijer solution. If not, put the correct password in your .env file.

Comment: phpmyadmin password field is empty, and @DaanMeijer method didn't work.

Comment: Might be a silly question, but worth asking.  Do you have the correct database name in there?  It looks like you are connecting to a DB called `products`, and querying a tabled that is also called products.

Comment: If you are on **MAMP** I'd make sure the port is correct because I noticed that sometimes it uses 8889 instead of 3306

Comment: @AaronDressler That's correct. I think I'd get different error related with incorrect db name or smth, but right now it doesn't give me access... I'm on XAMPP (Vagrant).

Comment: Another observation (XAMPP - I turn off Apache/MYSQL), but the website still shows that error - even tho it whould say that it can't connect to it (right?)

Comment: I would try creating a new MySQL user with a password, and all necessary privs.  Then use the new creds in your .env file.  I have a feeling that Laravel or PHP might not be handling the blank password properly.  I found some other threads from people experiencing permissions issues when creating databases + users under certain circumstances in PhpMyAdmin.  The above fixed their problems as well.